# http.post - getting response data

Tags: angular, rxjs, httprequest, angular6

I'm trying to do a simple `http.post` call and then console.log the data. I want to use the latest coding techniques, so I'm trying to do this with rxjs, since it seems powerful, efficient, and hopefully futureproof.

I've used `.subscribe` before, but in all the [angular](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6) docs there's no subscribe, so it leads me to believe it's an older method and that it's not the best.

I've tried a plethora of code, here's some snippets below:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, retry, tap, map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { of } from 'rxjs';


readonly GCF_newReq_URL = 'https://us-eastern.my-app.cloudfunctions.net/newRequest';


async submitHandler(formDirective: FormGroupDirective) {

    this.loading = true;
    const formValue = this.reqForm.value;

    this.http.post(this.GCF_newReq_URL, formValue)
        .pipe(
            tap(res => console.log(res)),
            retry(3),
            catchError(err => {
                console.log(err)
                return of(err);
            }),
            map(res => console.log(res))
        )
        .subscribe(res => {
            console.log(res);
        });

}
```

I've tried `map`, `tap`, event `.subscribe` and I can't get anything out, it just says: `message: "Http failure during parsing for https://us-eastern.my-app.cloudfunctions.net/newRequest"`

This should be so easy, I must be over complicating it, but I cannot find any decent documentation.

**EDIT, adding cloud function code**

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
const cors = require('cors')({ origin: true });

import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
admin.initializeApp();


export const newRequest = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {

    return cors(request, response, () => {
        const data = request;

        if (!data) {
            response.status(400).send('ERROR you must supply data');
        }

        response.status(200).send("Hello from Firebase!");
    });

});
```

Comment: Seems like the request is not properly formatted, check the data you are sending and receiving. Secondly, the `map` operator which returns console doesn't seem right. I would get rid of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, try to define the type of data you expect to get back:

```
this.http.post<any>(url, {}).subscribe((data) => { console.log(data); }, (error) => { console.error(error); });
```

Instead of `any` you can define an interface matching the data you expect.

The i belive that the `pipe()` is from older Angular verions (I am not sure), but simply use the `subsribe()` function as the post method is returning an rxjs `Observable<>()`

Second, are you sure that the URL returns data? I know that "standard" REST post endpoints should return the created object, but it is not required.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer! I added the cloud function code to the bottom of my original question. So, it should be returing "Hello from Firebase!"

Comment: In my cloud function, I changed the `send("Hello from Firebase!")` to `send({message: "Hello from Firebase!"})` and after just `subscribe`ing, it seem to fix the mishaps I was having.